# format.js vs format.html in Rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I want to load a partial using AJAX in my `create` action.  From tutorials I know the way to do this is to include the line `format.js` alone by itself in the `respond_to` block and create a `create.js.erb` file.  But I have code in my `create` action which I need executed.  If I put all of this code within a `format.js {}` block the partial doesn't get loaded.  I guess I'm not sure what should be included inside this block?

This sort of works:

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|

  format.html do
    session[:user_params].deep_merge!(params[:user]) if params[:user]
    @user = User.new(session[:user_params])
    @user.current_step = session[:user_step]
    if params[:prev_button]
      @user.previous_step
    elsif @user.last_step?
      @user.save
    else
      @user.next_step
    end
    session[:user_step] = @user.current_step
    if @user.new_record?
      render :new
    else
      session[:user_step] = session[:user_params] = nil
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to Friends First!"
      redirect_to @user
    end
  end
  format.js
end
end
```

My **new.html.erb** looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <div id="partial">
    <%= render "#{@user.current_step}", :f => f %>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.submit "Previous", class: "btn btn-primary", :name => "prev_button" unless @user.first_step? %>
    <%= f.submit "Next", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

But for some reason `@user.first_step?` is not working once I load a partial.

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#partial").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('step2')) %>");
```

What I really want is this: `render(@user.current_step)`

Comment: Show how you're calling ajax.  Type has to be script to get js.erb called.  Also, test the js.erb with just an alert('Test');

Comment: Ok, I added the rest of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all your logic and then handle proper format. Furthermore you can use more than one format for your views.

[There is](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/blob/develop/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb#L17-L30) and example from Diaspora source code:

```
  def create
    post = current_user.find_visible_shareable_by_id(Post, params[:post_id])
    @comment = current_user.comment!(post, params[:text]) if post

    if @comment
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json{ render :json => CommentPresenter.new(@comment), :status => 201 }
        format.html{ render :nothing => true, :status => 201 }
        format.mobile{ render :partial => 'comment', :locals => {:post => @comment.post, :comment => @comment} }
      end
    else
      render :nothing => true, :status => 422
    end
  end
```

You shouldn't do any redirects if something fail because user stay at page anyway. But you might want use client-side validation.

So you might use `format.js` for your success case and reload part of your HTML using partial. For example:

```
# create.js.erb
$("#js-user-panel").html("<%= j render("users/panel", :user => @user %>");
# ... create div with flash message here and etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to load partial on `new` page, so do it for `new` action, not `create`. And do it the way you said.